# How to use sprite images in html/css and toggle change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, sprite

I am trying to use it this way:

**CSS**

```
#sprite2 {
   background: url(../images/csg_sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}

.collapse_down{ background-position: 0 0; width: 16px; height: 16px; } 
.collapse_up{ background-position: 0 -66px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sprite2"><span id="splink1" class="collapse_down">Defaults</span>
```

**CHANGE by jQuery**

```
$('#splink1').attr("class", 'collapse_up');
```

The problem I face is that the image is applied for the div=sprite2 and not for the span I want for.

How to fix so on the left of the text to display the sprite, and when I toggle it, to change the image to up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sprite2 {
   background: url(../images/csg_sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
   display:inline-block;
}

<div  id="splink1" class="sprite2 collapse_down"></div>Defaults
```

background position property applied only when id or class which includes background  image added to it .

Comment: ehm you can't use class two times, it should be `class="sprite2 collapse_down"`

Comment: It starts to work, but doesn't float on the left. Can I make somehow to float on left, or have a new html node to occupy the exact space of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simply:

Change your CSS from this:

```
#sprite2 {
   background: url(../images/csg_sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

to this:

```
#sprite2 span {
   background: url(../images/csg_sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Comment: It starts to work, but doesn't float on the left. Can I make somehow to float on left, or have a new html node to occupy the exact space of the image. Also when I call the jQuery call to change the class it doesn't change the image.